# On linear recurrences of $2$nd order changing sign infinitely many times

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$  of real numbers satisfying the recurrence
$$x_{n+2} = a x_{n+1} + b x_{n}$$

where $a$, $b$ real such that the characteristic equation $\lambda^2 - a \lambda - b = 0$ has non-real roots. Show that if $(x_n)$ is not identical $0$ then it contains infinitely many positive numbers and infinitely many negative numbers.

Note: probably a known result, and not difficult to prove.

I would appreciate any feedback, thank you for your attention.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's sketch the solution. If $\alpha$, $\beta= \bar \alpha$ are the roots of $t^2 - a t - b = 0$ then we have $x_n = u\alpha^n + v \beta^n$ for all $n\ge 0$. Since $x_n$ are real, we have $v = \bar u$, so $x_n = u\alpha^n + \bar u \bar \alpha^n$. In the end, $x_n = p q^n \cos( n \phi + \psi)$, with $p$, $q>0$, $\phi\in (0, 2 \pi)$, and a little trigonometry finishes it. ( this is the solution of @dxiv:).

Comment: Do you mean it has purely imaginary root? or complex root with non zero imaginary part? just to make sure.

Comment: @Binxu Wang王彬旭: Oh, I meant non-real, so I modified to that. Thank you!

Comment: There's a formula for $x_n$ in terms of $n$ and the roots of the characteristic equation. Do you know that formula?

Comment: Related: [positivity of recursion $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}-\rho ^2 x_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595486/positivity-of-recursion-x-n2-x-n1-rho-2-x-n/).

Comment: @dxiv: Oh yes, so that does it, thank you!